# How connect to emr mastere node when Master public DNS points to internal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I am trying to connect to emr master node as described here [enter link description here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-connect-master-node-ssh.html):

[image]

but putty report me:

[image]

Execution of `aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id my_cluster_id` gives me the **same** `ip-XX-XXX-X-XXX.us-west-1.compute.internal` master public DNS name as on Web UI which can not be reolved to any IP address. Is there a way to setup emr cluster with real public dns address for master node?

Comment: Anyone may be in trouble connecting the master DNS, you should check either the EMR was provisioned in public or private subnet. see description in the following boto3 [link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow)
MasterPublicDnsName (string) --
The DNS name of the master node. If the cluster is on a private subnet, this is the private DNS name. On a public subnet, this is the public DNS name

Answer (score 0):

What are your VPC/subnet rules, it is most likely that you are locked in a private subnet, though it is a good security practice to have defensive network rules, it comes with a cost of not able to access. You have a couple of options

1) [Relax your VPC/subnet rule to allow incoming traffic](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/securely-access-web-interfaces-on-amazon-emr-launched-in-a-private-subnet/) - only for your IP, beyond which ec2 nodes created with those rule(s) will have a public master IP.

2) [Add a bastion host](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/securely-connect-to-linux-instances-running-in-a-private-amazon-vpc/) - which has a public IP that proxies to nodes on your private subnet

Comment: Yep, for the first one you might create a security group and attach them to your EMR.